# What's the easiest way to generate a List<int> of ordered numbers in C#?

Tags: c#

This seems like a no-brainer:

```
List<int> steporders = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
 steporders.Add(i);
}
```

But I figure there's some simpler, better or more clever way I haven't thought of. Is there?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can do it easily like this:

```
List<int> steporders = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();
```

Comment: Be careful with this. That's not "the numbers from 1 to 10". That's "10 numbers, starting from 1".  People are often confused when they try to change this code to, say (10,20) -- that's not the numbers from 10 to 20, that's 20 numbers, starting from 10.

Comment: One should say System.Linq.Enumerable (so it will be clearer that you need .NET 3.5 for this, does not work in earlier versions).

Answer (score -1):

A friend of mine always thought me, I should not answer questions before I know what its about: you have one of those :)

Why do you need a List with numbers from 1-10? This seems quite useless (at least without any context).

Comment: It's to provide a list of seed values for an ASP.net MVC dropdown list to set the order of a "step" as part of a "plan". For prototyping purposes, I just wanted to fill it with numbers 1-10.

Comment: Could also be just a prototype for a test.